# no entiendo por que no se ejecuta esta opcion del codigo

Tags: contentvalues

he seguido paulatinamente este ejercicio, el el video seejecuta la funcion creada, pero para mi no se ejecuta

def limpiarCampos():

```
miNombre.set("")
miId.set("")
miApellido.set("")
miDireccion.set("")
miPass.set("")
textocomentario.delete(1.0, END)
```

ya he asignado la funcion a la opcion pero me crea el error:
TypeError: Variable.set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Comment: [contentvalues] nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. ¿Qué lenguaje es? Corrige la etiqueta, y agrega triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tu código, para poder visualizarlo correctamente. Por último, dale un título _descriptivo_ a tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola Federico, aparte de etiquetar correctamente la pregunta (que si no me equivoco son [tag:python] y [tag:tkinter]) y demás detalles que te señalan, agrega **el código donde creas esas  variables** (supongo que `tkinter.StringVar`), el error no esta en el código que muestras y estoy bastante seguro de que el problema es que no estas instanciando las clases....